# ms access query (ms access freezes)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this report and need to add totals for each person (the red circle)
[existing report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1lau.jpg)

[new report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEfSZ.jpg)

I cannot change the existing report so I export data from MS SQL to MS Access and create a new report there. I got it working for one employee but have trouble with a query which would for multiple employees.

This query extract data use as input:

```
SELECT [TIME].[RCD_NUM], [TIME].[EMP_ID], [TIME].[PPERIOD], [TIME].[PRUN], [TIME].[TDATE], [TIME].[PC], [TIME].[RATE], [TIME].[HOURS], [TIME].[AMOUNT], [TIME].[JOB_ID], [TIME].[UPDATED], [TIME].[UPDATED_BY], [TIME].[LOG_DATE], [TIME].[ORIGINAL_REC_NUM]
FROM [TIME]
WHERE ((([TIME].[EMP_ID])=376) And (([TIME].[TDATE])<=#12/31/2006# And ([TIME].[TDATE])>=#1/1/2006#) And (([TIME].[PC])<599));
```

this query populates the report:

```
SELECT *
FROM TIME1
WHERE RCD_NUM = (SELECT Max(RCD_NUM) FROM [TIME1] UQ WHERE UQ.PPERIOD = [TIME1].PPERIOD AND UQ.PC = [TIME1].PC);
```

the problem is if I remove EMP_ID from the first query like this

```
SELECT [TIME].[RCD_NUM], [TIME].[EMP_ID], [TIME].[PPERIOD], [TIME].[PRUN], [TIME].[TDATE], [TIME].[PC], [TIME].[RATE], [TIME].[HOURS], [TIME].[AMOUNT], [TIME].[JOB_ID], [TIME].[UPDATED], [TIME].[UPDATED_BY], [TIME].[LOG_DATE], [TIME].[ORIGINAL_REC_NUM]
FROM [TIME]
WHERE ((([TIME].[TDATE])<=#12/31/2006# And ([TIME].[TDATE])>=#1/1/2006#) And (([TIME].[PC])<599));
```

**then the second query doesn't work** and ms access freezes when running this query.

any help/idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat**:  I won't pretend to know the precise cause of the problem, but I have had to repeatedly refactor queries in Access to get them working even though the original SQL statements are completely valid in regards to syntax and logic.  Sometimes I've had to convolute a sequence of queries just to avoid bugs in Access.  Access is often rather dumb and will simply (re)execute queries and subqueries exactly as given without optimization.  At other times Access will attempt to combine queries by performing some internal optimizations, but sometimes those introduce frustrating bugs. Something as simple as a name change or column reordering can be the difference between a functioning query and one that crashes or freezes Access.

---

First consider:

- Can you leave the data on SQL Server and link to the results in Access (rather than export/importing it into Access)?  Even if you need or prefer to use Access for creating the actual report, you could use all the power of SQL Server for querying the data--it is likely less buggy and more efficient.

  - Common best practice is to create SQL Server stored procedures that return just what data you need in Access.  A pass-through query is created in Access to retrieve the data, but all data operations are performed on the server.
- Perhaps this is just a performance issue where limiting the set by `[EMP_ID]` selects a small subset, but the full table is large enough to "freeze" Access.

  - How long have you let Access remain frozen before killing the process?  Be patient... like many, many minutes (or hours).  Start it in the morning and check after lunch. :)  It might eventually return a result set.  This does not imply it is tolerable or that there is no other solution, but it can be useful to know if it eventually returns data or not.
  - How many possible records are there?
  - Are the imported data properly indexed?  Add indexes to all key fields and those which are used in WHERE clauses.
  - Is the database located on a network share or is it local?  Try copying the database to a local drive.

Other hints:

- Try the BETWEEN operator for dates in the WHERE clause.

---

Try refactoring the "second" query by performing a join in the FROM clause rather than the WHERE clause.  In doing this, you may also want to save the subquery as a named query (just as `[TIME1]` is saved).  Whether or not a query is saved or embedded in another statement CAN change the behavior of Access (see caveat) even though the results should be identical.

Here's a version with the embedded aggregate query.  Notice how all column references are qualified with the source.  Some of the original query's columns do not have a source alias prefixing the column name.  Remember the caveat... such picky details can affect Access behavior.:

```
SELECT TIME1.*
FROM TIME1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT UQ.PPERIOD, UQ.PC, Max(UQ.RCD_NUM) As Max_RCD_NUM
   FROM [TIME1] UQ
   GROUP BY UQ.PPERIOD, UQ.PC) As TIMEAGG
  ON (TIME1.PPERIOD = TIMEAGG.PPERIOD) And (TIME1.PC = TIMEAGG.PC)
    AND (TIME1.RCD_NUM = TIMEAGG.Max_RCD_NUM)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your suggestions. I would rather do it in Access (local) for safety reason (at least for now) since I didn't design the original MS SQL database. When I let run the my query the Task Manager shows 'Access not responding ...' The number of records should not be a problem since the first query selects only about 3500 records. I tried your query and it looks promising - it doesn't freeze, gives some records, unfortunately it also gives me an error message 'Syntax error in FROM clause' in both Open and Edit options and I cannot either use the data or edit this query.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't understand how a query returns records and an error "in FROM clause".  If there is an error in the FROM clause, it should not be returning any records at all.  Also, what do you mean that you "cannot either use the data or edit this query"?  Do you mean that you can't edit the SQL or that you can't edit the data once returned in the datasheet?  If you mean the data in the datasheet, that is correct--it is not updateable because it joins to an aggregate query, but as far as I could tell that is not important since this is just for a report.

Comment: Yes, it returns records and shows the error message on top of it at the same time. When I click 'OK' on the error message the records disappear (the recordset widnow closes). When I open the query in Edit the same happens - error message, click, closes everything.

Comment: Perplexing.  I've never experienced that particular behavior.  Have you tried repairing and compacting the database?  As I mentioned in the answer, try saving and running the embedded subquery as a named query.  Does it run without error?  If that works, then edit the "second" query to join on the newly-saved query instead of the embedded statement.

Comment: I was able to make and run a report your query, no error messages there. But results are not correct - some missing employees (got 27 of 75), missing pay periods, some incorrect amounts for specific employees and periods. Running the embedded subquery as a named query was fine without error.

Comment: Glad you got the query working without error, but all that is now beyond this question, especially without knowing many other details of the data.  I would be suspicious of the export/import process fidelity.  Are all values being transferred correctly?  Are you importing directly via ODBC link or via text CSV file? Can you verify all rows and columns individually after the import?  Are there problems with formatting?  I suggest running various data validation queries to ensure all data is there and not being corrupted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and help. I imported via text CSV file.  The import was correct, I got all data to MS Access; I am able to see what records are missing or incorrect in MS Access so will try to find a reason/pattern for those missing/incorrect records.

Comment: Okay, best of luck.  But for what it's worth, you statement again seems contradictory :).  The import is correct, but you imply that there are missing/incorrect data.  I assume that means the values are being excluded in the export from SQL Server?  Good luck anyway and please post another question if need with new details.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding; I meant the import from MS SQL to Access was correct but the missing/incorrect data were in the report I ran based on your query (not in the imported data). Thanks again!